# Как получить номер каждой строки при запросе?

Tags: postgresql

Вот запрос SELECT id,name FROM table

Выведется допустим

```
id  name 
1 - арбуз
41 - ананас 
23 - яблоко
```

...

А нужно

```
number id  name 
1      1 - арбуз
2      41 - ананас 
3      23 - яблоко
```

То есть номер каждой строки из выборки по порядку

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 SELECT id,name, ROW_NUMBER() over() as number FROM table;
```

Comment: да, то что нужно